# ntfsdecrypt - Key does not have an EFS purpose OID

Tags: certificate, linux, ntfs, efs

I'm trying to copy EFS-encrypted files from an NTFS partition using:

```
ntfsdecrypt -k mycert.pfx /dev/sda2 -i 32768
```

and I get:

```
Key does not have an EFS purpose OID
Failed to extract the private RSA key.
```

**More info:**

- The password is indeed correct (the error is different when entering something else).
- I have previously (recently) used the same certificate and method with success.
- I'm on Arch Linux 5.10.20-1-lts and using ntfsdecrypt v2017.3.23 (libntfs-3g).

What's the EFS purpose OID?

What's the problem?

Comment: Error says that certificate doesn't have `Encrypting File System (1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.4)` usage in Enhanced Key Usage certificate extension.

Comment: @Crypt32 Thank you. Interesting. It did work a few weeks ago. Now I copied the certificate from another backup and that's identical. Only my arch installation has changed.

Comment: Finally, I used a Windows Installation on a USB HDD to import the certificate and decrypt the files, with no issues. So, the problem has to be either a bug in ntfsdecrypt, or yet another M$ technical barrier (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_litigation#Antitrust).

Comment: I more convinced to think that `ntfsdecrypt` is wrong.

Comment: @Crypt32 You're probably correct. Thanks again.

Comment: Same result with ntfsdecrypt v2021.8.22 (on Arch based SystemRescueCD). If it's a bug, it's strange that it's still there. Basically, there's now way right now to decrypt EFS encrypted files...